# Help understanding training stacked autoencoders

Tags: neural-networks, train, autoencoders

I've been learning about stacked autoencoders, but wasn't entirely sure how to train them. From what I understand, given layers $h_1,h_2,...,h_n$, we greedily train as follows

```
For every h in hidden_layers:
    let prev_hs be all the previously trained hidden layers
    let transformed = prev_hs(input_x)
    train h'(h(transformed)) ~ transformed
    delete h'
    add h to list of previously trained hidden layers
```

Then for fine tuning, we do

```
Initialize new hidden layers h1', h2',...,hn' with size hn, h(n-1),..., h2, h1
Train hn'(...(h2'(h1'(hn(...(h2(h1(input_x)))))))) ~ input_x
```

Is this correct, and if not, what does the training procedure look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first part, the training of the new layer is on the output of the previous layer (transformed in your code), not x. Besides that I am not sure fine tuning is necessary.
Also, I think you should keep the decoding layers from the training part. You can combine them to create a full autoencoder, or discard them when building a classifier

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo and I've just fixed it. How would it be possible to use the decoding layers? `If h1'(h1(x)) ~ x ` and `h2'(h2(h1(x))) ~ x`, how would you use `h1'`?

Comment: h2'(h2(h1(x))) ~ h1(x) because the second layer tries to represent the output of the first layer. So I believe you should stack the decoders in reverse order to retrieve x